# Rails partials not rendering

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've written some partials but they don't seem to be rendering. Some of the other posters who have reported the same issue made the mistake of using <% ... %> for embedded ruby code instead of <%= ... %>. I'm not making that error, so I'm not sure why my partials aren't rendering. Perhaps someone will see something in my code which I am missing. I'm not sure if it's relevant...but the call to render :partial occurs inside a form_tag. Also, @teachers is an array of Teacher objects that is defined and populated in the registration_two controller action.

Here is a code excerpt from my view, static_pages/registration_two.html.erb

```
<div id="teachers"> 
<%= render :partial => 'teacher', :collection => @teachers %>
</div>
<%= link_to_function "Add Instructor" do |page|
page.insert_html :bottom, :teachers, :partial => 'teacher', :object => Teacher.new
end %>
```

And here is my partial, static_pages/_teacher.html.erb

```
<div class="teacher">
<% fields_for teacher do |teacher_field| %>
  <p>
    Instructor Name: <%= teacher_field.text_field :name %>


    Email: <%= teacher_field.text_field :email %>
    <%= link_to_function "remove", "$(this).up('.teacher').remove()" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Right now the only thing that shows up is the 'Add Instructors' button, which doesn't do anything.

I'm essentially trying to imitate Ryan Bates' approach for dynamic form submissions. 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<% fields_for` with `<%= fields_for`

Sidenote, you could simply use:

```
<%= render @teachers %>
```